# Is there anyway to clear cahced RAM used by Chrome, without restarting laptop?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am not 100% whether Chrome browser caches RAM or may do anything similar to that. What I am facing is:

- My laptop is Ryzen based, so Vega 8 gfx reserves 2GB RAM, so I get 6GB RAM to use
- usually, from fresh restart, I can play game normally, without any hassel
- but if I use chrome for a while, then close it (not running minimized, closed it), and open the game to play, I see less Memory performance issues, like low fps, lagging fps, 10-15fps.
- then, I restart, and re-launch the game, and works smoothly.

Thats, why I am guessing, chrome may cache some RAM, while browsing it, which is not released when I close it. I want to know if there is any solution for that, so that I do not need to restart everytime, before I play games after browsing chrome.

Comment: 2 things to check or consider: 1) windows uses unused memory to cache files (it is instantly released so it is technically not in use. This might mean that some of the game archive files are cached by OS and file reads for streaming/loading game assets are actually being pulled from cached memory. This is faster. When chrome is run, the cache for the game files are released, this slows the asset streaming potentially until re-cached. 2) laptops often switch dynamically between CPU video and dedicated video. Low FPS sometimes is because the laptop hasn't properly switched to to dedicated GPU

Comment: @Yorik , the 2nd thing is 100% sure that I am not using CPU for running that game, Nvidia always notifys me. It is not a problem. The 1st option you have suggested, this can be probable. The thing I want to release the chromes used one before I start the game. I mean, is there any way that exists!

Comment: it is released automatically, without need to do anything. The "slowdown" is just from actually reading from disk instead of cached memory-backed files *for the game*. Some people suggest using "cache cleaners" but IMO is just snake oil that actually *causes* the problem. In any event, you should use Process Monitor and Process Explorer to poke around a little. It isn't clear to me that Chrome is the issue (nor memory). And Process Explorer (run it as admin) especially may help you see what is actually going on so you can target specific processes.

Comment: When it is slow start Task Manager - Details tab and sort on memory and also CPU. Take screen shots and edit them into your question. Also on the Performance tab of Task Manager take a screenshot of the GPU graph and edit them into your question.